# Redux reducer doesn't update key

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hello I am trying to get the reducer "removePlayer" to update the state it generates to have a selectedPlayerIndex of -1 but I can't seem to get it to work, I've looked for similar questions but couldn't find anything that is informative enough to answer my question.

Here is the code

```
import * as PlayerActionTypes from '../actiontypes/player';

const initialState = {
    players: [{
        name: 'Jim Hoskins',
      score: 31,
        created: '11/8/2016',
        updated: '11/9/2016'
    },
    {
        name: 'Andrew Chalkley',
        score: 20,
        created: '11/9/2016',
        updated: '11/10/2016'
    },
    {
        name: 'Alena Holligan',
        score: 50,
        created: '11/11/2016',
        updated: '11/12/2016'
    }
    ],
    selectedPlayerIndex: -1
}


export default function Player(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case PlayerActionTypes.REMOVE_PLAYER:
    const removePlayerList = [
      ...state.players.slice(0, action.index),
      ...state.players.slice(action.index + 1)
    ];
      return {
                  ...state,
          players: removePlayerList,
          selectedPlayerIndex: -1
      }

    case PlayerActionTypes.SELECT_PLAYER:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedPlayerIndex: action.index
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

here is the top level component

```
class Scoreboard extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    players: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    selectedPlayerIndex: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { dispatch, players, selectedPlayerIndex } = this.props;
    const addPlayer = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.addPlayer, dispatch);
    const removePlayer = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.removePlayer, dispatch);
    const updatePlayerScore = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.updatePlayerScore, dispatch);
    const selectPlayer = bindActionCreators(PlayerActionCreators.selectPlayer, dispatch)

    const playerComponents = players.map((player, index) => (
      <Player
        index={index}
        name={player.name}
        score={player.score}
        key={player.name}
        updatePlayerScore={updatePlayerScore}
        removePlayer={removePlayer}
        selectPlayer={selectPlayer}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <div className="scoreboard">
        <Header players={players} />
        <div className="players">
          { playerComponents }
        </div>
        <AddPlayerForm addPlayer={addPlayer} />

        <div className="player-detail">
          <PlayerDetail players={players} selectedPlayerIndex={selectedPlayerIndex} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    players: state.players,
    selectedPlayerIndex: state.selectedPlayerIndex
  }
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Scoreboard);
```

Here is the component that child component Where remove_player is dispatched

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';

const Player = props => (
  <div className="player">
    <div className="player-name" onClick={() => props.selectPlayer(props.index)}>
      <a className="remove-player"
        onClick={() => props.removePlayer(props.index)}>
        ✖
      </a>
      {props.name}
    </div>
    <div className="player-score">
      <Counter
        index={props.index}
        updatePlayerScore={props.updatePlayerScore}
        score={props.score}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I've tried to keep the code to only what I think is necessary, if you need to see other parts of the app just let me know.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "what" isn't working? Do you have Redux Devtools to track the state changes and actions? Can you add the code where you're dispatching your actions?
For the REMOVE_PLAYER action you dont need ...state before the rest of the state as you're updating both keys in the state already.

Comment: This works in an isolated environment: https://codesandbox.io/s/5zmqj9v2pp I suspect the problem may be in your dispatch. Perhaps an action type mismatch causing it to fall through to the default case?

Comment: @Genzume after I looked at the redux extention it seems that when I invoke the REMOVE_PLAYER action it immediately also invokes the SELECT_PLAYER action.

Comment: @Sparky Would it help if I provide the components that are pertinent?

Comment: @Ricky can you update the code to include the Player component which is calling add/remove?

Comment: @Genzume I've updated the post to show where it is being dispatched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got a nested onClick event. When you click on removePlayer it propagates up to the selectPlayer. This is due to event bubbling. You need to stop the event from propagating up to the selectPlayer component.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

You'll need to change the removePlayer onClick function to something like:

```
function(event) {
    props.removePlayer(props.index);
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

More information on event bubbling and capturing can be found [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: That's the problem! Thanks! this was very helpful